# Changing options in a dynamically created select box JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Before I get started I know I need to delegate to a static DOM element, I'm just having trouble understanding how to do that in this situation.

What I'm trying to do is create a dynamic select box `.userDrop` when `.addNew` is clicked. After this is done I want the user to select an option `#secDrop` when selected a change event calls the database and all users from that section are put into `.userDrop`.

I just cant figure out how to delegate `.userDrop`.

JS

```
$("#secDrop").on("change", function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "serverCode/_grabUsers.php",
    data: {
      secID: $("#secDrop").val()
    },
    success: function(data) {

      $(".userDrop").children().remove();

      var users = JSON.parse(data);
      alert(data)
      for (i = 0; i < users["value"].length; i++) {
        $('.userDrop').append($('<option>', {
          value: users["value"][i],
          text: users["text"][i]
        }));
      }
    }
  });
});
}

$(document).on("click", ".addNew", function() {
  var newDiv = "<div class='block'><select class='userDrop'> <
    /select</div > ";

  $(".scheduleColumns").append(newDiv);
});
```

HTML

```
<select id='secDrop'>
    <option value='0'>All Sections</option>
    <option value='1'>Section</option>
</select>

<div class='scheduleColumns'>
</div>

<input type='button' class='addNew' value='Add'>
```

**Edit**

JS

Edit based on @Barmar

Still can't figure out how to make this work.

```
var users;

        $(".scheduleColumns").on("change", ".userDrop", function() {
            alert();
            $(this).children().remove();
            for(i = 0; i<users["value"].length; i++){
                $(this).append($('<option>', {
                    value:  users["value"][i],
                    text:   users["text"][i]
                }));
            }
        });

        $("#secDrop").on("change", function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "serverCode/_grabUsers.php",
                data: {secID: $("#secDrop").val()},
                success: function(data){
                    users = JSON.parse(data);
                    $(".userDrop").change();
                }
            });  
        });
```

Comment: You have an extra `}` after the first event binding.

Comment: `var users = JSON.parse(data)` declares a local variable, it doesn't update the global variable.

Comment: I don't understand your code. Why would you change the options in a menu when the user selects something from that same menu?

Comment: When you select an option from .secDrop it sends a database call with that value then returns some JSON with every user in that section. I want to apply that JSON to a dynamically created select box .userDrop.

Comment: What is `.secDrop`, do you mean `#secDrop`? That seems to be what you're doing in `$(".userDrop").append(...)`.

Comment: BTW, `$(".userDrop").children().remove();` can be simplified to `$(".userDrop").empty()`.

Comment: I meant #secDrop my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my weird way of doing it. If anyone has a better more efficient way of doing this please respond

JS

```
var users;

            $(".scheduleColumns").on("change", ".userDrop", function() {
                $(this).children().remove();
                for(i = 0; i<users["value"].length; i++){
                    $(this).append($('<option>', {
                        value:  users["value"][i],
                        text:   users["text"][i]
                    }));
                }
            });

            $("#secDrop").on("change", function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "serverCode/_grabUsers.php",
                    data: {secID: $("#secDrop").val()},
                    success: function(data){
                        users = JSON.parse(data);
                        $(".scheduleColumns .userDrop").change();   
                    }
                });  
            });
```

Comment: I still don't understand why you're updating the `.userDrop` select in its own `change` handler. That means every time you select something from that menu it will remove all its contents and re-add them. As a result, you'll lose the selection you just made.

Comment: You should just update it once in the AJAX success function, not every time the user changes something in `.userDrop`.

Answer (score 1):

`.scheduleColumns` is the static element that you delegate from:

```
$(".scheduleColumns").on("change", ".userDrop", function() {
    ...
});
```

The code in the function can use `$(this)` to refer the specific `userDrop` menu they changed.

Also, `class='.userDrop'` should be `class="='userDrop'` when creating the element. The `.` is used in selectors, not the element itself.

Comment: would i then have to trigger change when secDrop was changed

Comment: `$("#secDrop").val(newValue).change()` will trigger the change event on it.

Comment: userDrop doesnt need to be changed. I'm trying to change secDrop and change what is appended into the dynamically created .userDrop

Comment: You need to clarify the question.

Comment: "What I'm trying to do is create a dynamic select box .userDrop when .addNew is clicked. After this is done I want the user to select an option #secDrop when selected a change event calls the database and all users from that section are put into .userDrop." I don't know how much clearer I can get. This explains exactly what I'm trying to accomplish @Barmar

Comment: If I didn't understand it the first time, what makes you think quoting it will help?>

Comment: Your original code for `#secDrop` change was correct. It puts the options into `.userDrop`.

Comment: Maybe you're not processing the JSON correctly, maybe it should be `users[i].value`, not `users.value[i]`. If you post sample JSON I can confirm that.

Comment: The code to update the `.userDrop` contents should be in the `#secDrop` change event, not the `.userDrop` change event.

Comment: My JSON works I've tried it with a static .userDrop. I just cant seem to delegate the dynamic .userDrop 's correctly

Comment: My answer shows how to delegate correctly. I don't know why it's not working for you.